# Bat file wont open things from desktop

Tags: batch-file

I have a bat file that I would like to open another bat file minimized from the desktop. I tried doing this:

```
@echo off

start /min "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\coolkids.bat"

exit
```

But it just opened up a blank command prompt, even though "coolkids.bat" has commands in it.

I have a windows 10 PC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first quoted argument of `start` is taken to be the caption of the new window. Try the following instead, and check `start /?` for the full syntax.

```
start /min "" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\coolkids.bat"
```